# Pass data back to parent controller for iOS development

Tags: ios

i have problem to display selected data into detaillabeltext in one of my row of section, beside reload the whole table view any other method to reload only certain row of section?

//RootViewController.m (parent controller)

```
-(void) selectedData:(NSString*) text
{
  selectedAbsenceType = text;

  NSLog(@"the absence type select is %@",text);
}

-(void) (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
}

NSDictionary *dictionary = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

if([cellValue isEqual: @"Absence Type"])
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = selectedAbsenceType;
}
else if([cellValue isEqual:@"Start Date"])
{
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = selectedDate;
}
return cell;
```

}

===========================================================================================
i have a problem when i calling the method of the protocol, it keep prompt me a ARC Semantic Issue at this statement

```
[self.delegate selectedData: (NSString*) [self.absenceTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];:
```

//child.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol childViewControllerDelegate;

@interface AbsenceTypesViewController : UITableViewController
{
   id<childViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<childViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property NSArray *absenceTypes;
@end

@protocol childViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) selectedData:(NSString*) text;
@end

//child.m

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{

NSString *selectedCell = nil;
selectedCell = [self.absenceTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.delegate selectedData: (NSString*) [self.absenceTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

//[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"%@", selectedCell);

}
```

Comment: What does log show `NSLog(@"%@", selectedCell);`?

Comment: Your question is not clear.... which data do you want to send back to the viewcontroller???

Comment: i want pass the data selected(selectedCell) in the table view to the first controller and display in the section of table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `{
   id<childViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
}` inside user class interface.`id<childViewControllerDelegate>delegate;` means strong variable which will be released only when holding object is released. But in property declaration you are mentioning delegate as weak property. Hence the ARC Semantic is giving you warning. You can also make the delegate  weak by declaring it as weak explicitly like `__weak id<childViewControllerDelegate>delegate;`

Try replacing the .h file content with this.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  
@class AbsenceTypesViewController;

@protocol childViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) selectedData:(NSString*) text;
@end

@interface AbsenceTypesViewController : UITableViewController
{
   id<childViewControllerDelegate>delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic,weak) id<childViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property NSArray *absenceTypes;
@end
```

So that you have forward declaration of class.

Comment: i removed the { id<childViewControllerDelegate>delegate; } but the error still there :ARC semantic issue - no known instance method for selector 'selectedData' at this statement[self.delegate selectedData:(NSString*) selectedCell];

Comment: i am using ARC is it the cause i cant used the protocol and delegate method?

Comment: I tried your code and I did not receive any warnings. Anyway try the changes made and see if that works.

Comment: i pasted the code above but when i did a synthesize at .h file it prompted that: Existing instance variable 'delegate' for __weak property 'delegate' must be weak. do u got any idea? is it i need to put __weak id< childViewControllerDelegate> inside use class interface?

Comment: it is work after i applied __weak id< childViewControllerDelegate> in side user class interface. Btw, how can i display the selected data in table view detailLabelText because it is not working.Above is my latest code:

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can save all selected option of second view controller in NSMutable Array and save all components  separated by comma and send this array to your parent controller.

 NSMutableArray *selectedVal =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

      FirstViewController *FVC = (FirstViewController*)

         if ([FVC isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]])
         {

             [FVC setSelectedOption:[selectedVal componentsJoinedByString:@","]];


         }

         [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: what purpose for this statement  [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2]?

Comment: it just maintains stack of navigation controllers .